# How to replace a word in a txt using powershell

Tags: powershell

I joined the powershell comunity since one week, thus i'm blocking on a trivial problem:
I want to browse a txt file and change the first digit of each number of 6 digits to 8

Example:

*Old file*

```
2332             
abc              
234567
```

*Desired File*

```
2332  (no change)
abc   (no change)
834567 (change of the first digit to 8)
```

I've tried this code, but i have a problem with the replace line, can't find the right syntax for this line

```
$original_file = "C:\original.txt"
$destination_file =  "C:\new.txt"
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
$_ -replace "(\d{1})(\d{5})", "8"+"$2" } | 
Set-Content $destination_file
```

Thanks for the much needed help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good job on your first question. I've taken the liberty to format it a little to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$original_file = "C:\original.txt"
$destination_file = "C:\new.txt"
$file_content = Get-Content "$original_file"
Set-Content -Path "$destination_file" -Value ($file_content -replace "\b\d(\d{5})\b", "8`$1")
```

the regex will match:

- `\b` - Match a word boundary
- `\d` - Match a single digit
- `(\d{5})` - Match 5 digits and capture them in a group
- `\b` - Match a word boundary

then replace it with:

- `8` - The number 8
- `$1 - The captured group